# Properties of any structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, research

Bonjour, I've never made extensive researches in number theory, scared to lost myself, so... I would like to ask you something : Could you help me to find some sources(or anything else) about the distribution and the interactions/properties[...] of elements for any structures(if that does exist, but I'm pretty sure it exists, even if...).

I'll give you an exemple : Imagine you are working on the set of natural numbers, you would like to find the "informations" about the intrinsic properties/rules of that set (for instance, the distribution of numbers of the form $ak+b$ (it's only an example), the behavior when you apply a transformation compared to an abstract object, when you add $a$ and $b$ : be able to say if a+b will be even or odd (without doing the operation) and so on...).

I've try to be the more comprehensive that i could, but that stays a little bit confusing I guess. Sorry... If you want any kind of informations/precision, I'll be there.

Thanks.

Ps: I hope that you could have understand me without any trouble, because I'm a young french student (16 years old).

Comment: I think this is too broad.  There is a lot of structure in the natural numbers...polynomial arithmetic, distribution of primes, and so on.  Too much stuff to permit any sort of comprehensive reference guide.

Comment: I would recommend you to post specific examples that you have in mind as separate questions. This will improve your chance of getting an answer

Comment: Au cas où: les commentaires précédents te recommandent de restreindre le domaine de la question et poser une question plus précise (quitte à en poser plusieurs séparées), car il y a beaucoup trop à dire, la théorie des nombres c'est très vaste. N'hésite pas à préciser ton bagage (ce que tu sais déjà) en plus de ce que tu veux savoir. L'âge n'est qu'un indicateur imprécis.

Comment: Merci beaucoup Arnaud Mortier, j'avais compris, mais formulé ainsi c'est encore plus clair. About my mathematical level, I haven't any particular knowledge in number theory, but some in real analysis, abstract algebra and topology(I really love that). I'll follow your advices and try to express specific question in some others threads. I had in mind an extended Galois'-like theory(I'll say no more, because I probably have say nonsense, I need to do many researches). Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in mathematics, there is no general encyclopedia or database for the known mathematical structures and terms. You could look for numbers, for algebraic structures and for combinatorial structures.

Search for example in:

Google

Google Books

Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (https://oeis.org)

Encyclopedia of Combinatorial Structures (http://ecs.inria.fr)

Wolfram mathworld (http://mathworld.wolfram.com)

Wikipedia

Wikipedia: list of mathematical